# Fitting gif within parent div

Tags: css

I've used object-fit: contain to fit an image to a parent div plenty of times in the past, but for some reason I can't get this gif to fit within the speech_bubble parent div.

Here is my code-pen:
https://codepen.io/TheNomadicAspie/pen/vYmNwow

And here is my code:

```
.logo-animation {
  max-width: 50%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

This is the relevant part of the HTML:

```
<div id="speech_bubble" , class="speech-bubble">
<div id="logo_animation" , class="logo-animation"><img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/E0SE1bDv0sTbCH4p6V/giphy.gif?cid=790b761143fe1cebe2466c26bfb82fc6b178eb7ecad3874e&rid=giphy.gif"/></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give `object-fit:contain` to the **img** itself and gives it a `height:100%`, this works fine. Currently you are giving the `object-fit:contain` to the parent div of **img** while as per [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

> The CSS object-fit property is used to specify how an img or video
> should be resized to fit its container.

```
.logo-animation img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

CodePen Link for your reference: https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/rNmWvPv

Comment: @TheNomadicAspie Most Welcome Mate